# Stackexchange.redis lacks the "WAIT" support

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

i have 3 web api servers behind a load balancer which a client application is using.
i am using this library to access redis cluster with one master and few slaves.
the "WAIT" operation is not currently supported, and i need this functionality in order to store a newly created user session and wait until it replicates to all slaves to ensure that all following incoming calls from the client to read the session (which can come from my other application servers) won't fail (as it can try to read the key from a redis slave).

looking for some best practice for such implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`WAIT` is essentially a blocking operation, which violates the connection-sharing programming model that the library depends on (see more [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers.html#multiplexing)). So no, this isn't exposed.

We are discussing ideas to allow a more versatile pool/lease model *as well as* the default shared model, but right now: this doesn't exist. But this is what would make blocking commands "safe".

You could issue it manually via `Execute`, but if you do that: *you're on your own*; if it explodes or causes any kind of problem... have fun with that!

---

The following **is not supported** (essentially it issues a blocking operation), but if it works - it works; if it causes problems - it causes problems:

```cs
var tran = db.CreateTransaction();
_ = tran.StringSetAsync("mykey", cacheItem);
_ = tran.ExecuteAsync("wait", 2);
tran.Execute();
```

Comment: ive seen the Execute method exposed but couldn't find any example of how to use it  - in general and for WAIT in particular. can you direct me to such example/s? i intend to do some testings with it - and it is only needed for a very specific usage

Comment: @Liran something like `db.Execute("WAIT", 2);` (second parameter is args), but: **issuing blocking ops is unsupported**: whatever happens next: happens

Comment: @MarcGravell if we create new instance of ConnectionMultiplexer and doing the Set+Wait operations in that instance, could it potentially make problems to other places in the system that use different object?

Comment: @liraz just for the "long tail" (i.e. other readers), we discussed that via GitHub, the answer was "don't do that today, it would hurt you, but: we're working on it": 
 https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1225#issuecomment-617876946

Answer (score -1):

solved it finally - there was a missing parameter for the wait