# using .net StackExchange.Redis with "wait" isn't working as expected

Tags: redis, wait, stackexchange.redis

doing a R/W test with redis cluster (servers): 1 master + 2 slaves. the following is the key WRITE code:

```
var trans = redisDatabase.CreateTransaction();
Task<bool> setResult = trans.StringSetAsync(key, serializedValue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
Task<RedisResult> waitResult = trans.ExecuteAsync("wait", 3, 10000);
trans.Execute();
trans.WaitAll(setResult, waitResult);
```

using the following as the connection string:

```
[server1 ip]:6379,[server2 ip]:6379,[server3 ip]:6379,ssl=False,abortConnect=False
```

running 100 threads which do 1000 loops of the following steps:

1. generate a GUID as key and random as value of 1024 bytes
2. writing the key (using the above code)
3. retrieve the key using "var stringValue =
   redisDatabase.StringGet(key, CommandFlags.PreferSlave);"
4. compare the two values and print an error if they differ.

running this test a few times generates several errors - trying to understand why as the "wait" with (10 seconds!) operation should have guaranteed the write to all slaves before returning.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`WAIT` isn't supported by SE.Redis as explained by its prolific author at [Stackexchange.redis lacks the "WAIT" support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57871559/stackexchange-redis-lacks-the-wait-support/57871758#57871758)

Comment: Indeed you have, and they were etched into my heart and mind - hence I could reference them <3

Answer (score 0):

What about improving consistency guarantees, by adding in some "check, write, read" iterations?

1. SET a new key value pair (master node)
2. Read it (set CommandFlags to DemandReplica.
3. Not there yet? Wait and Try X times.
   4.a) Not there yet? SET again. go back to (3) or give up
   4.b) There? You're "done"

Won't be perfect but it should reduce probability of losing a SET??